# Как установить приоритет для определенной версии утилиты только для 1 юзера LINUX?

Tags: linux

Мне нужно установить приоритет python3.6 над python3.8 только для моего пользователя на linux хосте, как это сделать?

Comment: да просто запускайте нужную версию. с этим проблемы?

Comment: Нет, вам нужно построить виртуальное окружение (в понятии Python) для этого пользователя. Читайте документацию на virtual environment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/venv.html.

Answer (score -2):

Одно из *обходных* решений: в `~/.bashrc` прописать:

```
alias python3.6='python3.8'
```

Но лучше явно указать нужное название при запуске.

Comment: Нет. Читайте мой комментарий выше.